# Сохранить файл в win1251

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть задача записать текстовый файл в формате Windows-1251, стандартный fs как я понял может писать только в UTF. Есть ли простой способ это сделать?

Comment: кодировку можно указывать при записи: [fs.write(fd, data, position, encoding, callback)](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_data_position_encoding_callback)

Comment: @Grundy только windows-1251 там указать нельзя.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14551669/1016033

Comment: @AlexeyTen, ага, интересно. Но в том же вопросе ссылка на конвертер  дана

Comment: Вот только вопрос не про конвертер, с ним всё ясно

Comment: @vnn198 а про что?

Comment: Стандартный `fs.writeFile(Sync)` умеет писать буфер.